# WinUI UWP - How to create a custom style that inherits from it?

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui

I have added the nuget package for WinUI and added the merged dictionary in App.xaml and new style does appear for all controls that are not affected by the `Style` directives. However simple using of `Style` causes the Setters of `Style` to be applied to the original UWP templates and not to WinUI templates. For example this code:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="160"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
```

will cause that ComboBoxes appear without corner radius and with more thick borders than if the above is not applied.

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To override properties on the WinUI style, you can use [based-on styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/xaml-styles#use-based-on-styles).

So in your specific case, you can do the following:

```xml
<Style TargetType="ComboBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultComboBoxStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="160"/>
</Style>
```

That way, you create a new style which is based on the WinUI style (called DefaultComboBoxStyle) where you override the width property.